# Test-retest correlation for panel data

Tags: correlation, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, reliability, standardization

I've run an experiment in which subjects rate how much they like six different objects on a 1-5 scale on two occasions. I'd like to obtain a summary measure of how consistent are the subjects in their ratings from one occasion to the other.

Test-retest correlations seem one good choice, but the data are clustered, because each subject rates six objects, so I can't just run a correlation test across all the data points ignoring this clustering. Instead, I've tried fitting a Bayesian model akin to panel regression in which the scores given on the second occasion are predicted by the scores given on the first occasion for each individual. The model estimates a regression coefficient for each individual, as well as a regression coefficient over all subjects.

The model is the "hierarchical regression on individuals within groups" model of Kruschke (DBDA2E pp. 490-495), and is given below. The model estimates regression coefficients, but what I want is correlations for test-retest reliability. Does it make sense to compute z-scores within individuals and occasions (i.e. subtract from each score the mean and divide by the sd of the scores obtained for the specific individual and specific session from which the score was obtained) as input to the model (instead of raw scores) in order to obtain test-retest correlations? Are there better approaches? A Bayesian solution would be preferred.

Jags model:

```
# Standardize the data (this is not the within-subject and session 
# standardization I'm referring to above, this is standardization
# across subjects to speed up MCMC convergence)
data {
  Ntotal <- length(y)
  xm <- mean(x)
  ym <- mean(y)
  xsd <- sd(x)
  ysd <- sd(y)
  for (i in 1:length(y)) {
      zx[i] <- (x[i] - xm) / xsd
    zy[i] <- (y[i] - ym) / ysd
  }
}
# Specify the model for standardized data:
model {
  for (i in 1:Ntotal) {
    zy[i] ~ dt(zbeta0[s[i]] + zbeta1[s[i]] * zx[i], 1/zsigma^2, nu)
  }
  for (j in 1:Nsubj) {
    zbeta0[j] ~ dnorm(zbeta0mu, 1/(zbeta0sigma)^2)  
    zbeta1[j] ~ dnorm(zbeta1mu, 1/(zbeta1sigma)^2)
  }
  # Priors vague on standardized scale:
  zbeta0mu ~ dnorm(0, 1/(10)^2)
  zbeta1mu ~ dnorm(0, 1/(10)^2)
  zsigma ~ dunif(1.0E-3, 1.0E+3)
  zbeta0sigma ~ dunif(1.0E-3, 1.0E+3)
  zbeta1sigma ~ dunif(1.0E-3, 1.0E+3)
  nu <- nuMinusOne+1
  nuMinusOne ~ dexp(1/29.0)
  # Transform to original scale:
  for (j in 1:Nsubj) {
    beta1[j] <- zbeta1[j] * ysd / xsd  
    beta0[j] <- zbeta0[j] * ysd  + ym - zbeta1[j] * xm * ysd / xsd 
  }
  beta1mu <- zbeta1mu * ysd / xsd  
  beta0mu <- zbeta0mu * ysd  + ym - zbeta1mu * xm * ysd / xsd 
  sigma <- zsigma * ysd
}
```